# Angular scope does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, google-signin

I'm writing a simple web application, and I'm using a directive for google sign in.

When I set scope values in $on method, it does not work in my html page.

This is my javascript:

```
"use strict";
var loginApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial", "ngMessages","ngRoute", "directive.g+signin"]);


loginApp.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, $window) {

  $scope.pages       = ["login.html", "guess.html", "employee.html","admin.html"];
  $scope.currentPage = $scope.pages[0];

  $scope.openPage    = function (num) {
    console.log(num);
    $scope.currentPage = $scope.pages[num];
    console.log("asd");
  };

  $scope.profile = [];
  $scope.name;

  $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-success', function (event, authResult) {
          // User successfully authorized the G+ App
    console.log('Signed in!asd');
    var profile = authResult.getBasicProfile();
    // console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    // console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    // console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    // console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    $scope.name = profile.getName();
    console.log($scope.name);
    $scope.openPage(1);

  });

  $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-failure', function (event, authResult) {
    // User has not authorized the G+ App!
    console.log('Not signed into Google Plus.');
  });

});
```

Comment: What does `getBasicProfile()` do? Are console logs correct? Not a lot of troubleshooting details given here

Comment: I get users data with getBasicProfie(). Console log is correct.  
  The data of $scope.name is correct, but outside is not. This is my problem.

Comment: How is `$scope.currentPage` used in view? As an `ng-include`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn-t work too

Comment: Well if that's not working then where is `$scope.name` used. Show some relevant view html. Sounds like you should use a router also

Comment: <div class="main-block" layout="column">
  <google-plus-signin clientid="[MY_CLIENT_ID]]">
</div>
<b>{{name}}</b>

Comment: doesn't show `ng-controller` though

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
 ...

Comment: Can try calling `$scope.$apply()` but I think it will cause `digest in progress` error. Also using objects in scope models instead of primitive might help due to child scope created by `ng-include`

Comment: Update question itself instead of putting code in comment blocks

Comment: $scope.$apply() solved my problem. Thanks!